# If you are a miner can you accept your own transactions at no cost?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, mining, dapps, blocks

Let us say I am a miner. Can I accept my transactions into the blockchain at no fee to myself? And what do I lose?

Let us assume someone is running a dapp. Can they mine transactions of that dapp to make them free? Are there any dangers of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, not very often.

A miner can assemble a block full of transactions it made itself or from others that pay no gas. If the miner finds a nonce then the miner can commit that block.

However, consensus algorithms make it difficult for a lone miner to win the privilege of doing it. Mining pools are uniquely positioned to leverage transient miner advantages.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think I understand. Correct me if I am wrong. Because ethereum uses proof of work consensus algorithm the miner that finds the nonce first wins the privilege to mine the block. And for this reason it is hard for a lone miner to compete with mining pools that have massive computational power in order to mine a block. And that this is the hard part mining your own transactions.

Comment: I think you understand.